# LINQ or Lambda for two for loops

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

The code I have written works fine, this inquiry being purely for educational purposes. I want to know how others would do this better and cleaner. I especially hate the way I use two for loops to get data. There has to be a more efficient way.

I tried to do with LINQ but one of them is a class and the other one is just a string[].  So I couldn't figure out how to use it.

I have got a Document Name Table in my SQL database and Files in Content Folder.
I have got a Two list-  ListOfFileNamesSavedInTheDB and ListOfFileNamesInTheFolder.

Basically, I am getting all file names saved in Database and checking is it exist in the Folder, if not delete file name from the database.

```
 var clientDocList = documentRepository.Documents.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientID).ToList();

                 if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();


                foreach (var clientDoc in clientDocList)
                {
                    bool fileNotExist = true;
                    foreach (var file in fileList)
                    {
                        if (clientDoc.DocFileName.Trim().ToUpper()==file.ToUpper().Trim())
                        {
                            fileNotExist = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (fileNotExist)
                    {
                        documentRepository.Delete(clientDoc);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: In this code `fileNotExist` is never true. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Hi Dialecticus, I edited now..

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure of how you want your code to work but I believe you need something like this

```
        //string TextResult = "";
        ClientDocList documentRepository = GetClientDocList();
        var directoryPath = "";
        var clientID = 1;
        var clientDocList = documentRepository.Documents.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientID).ToList();

        if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath) || true) // I need to pass your condition
        {
            string[] files = new string[] { "file1", "file5", "file6" };  
            List<string> fileList = files.Select(x => x.Trim().ToUpper()).ToList(); // I like working with lists, if you want an array it's ok

            foreach (var clientDoc in clientDocList.Where(c => !fileList.Contains(c.DocFileName.Trim().ToUpper())))
            {
                //TextResult += $" {clientDoc.DocFileName} does not exists so you have to delete it from db";
                documentRepository.Delete(clientDoc);
            }

        }

        //Console.WriteLine(TextResult);
```

To be honest, I really don't like this line 
**fileList = files.Select(x => x.Trim().ToUpper()).ToList()**
so I would suggest you add a helper function comparing the list of file names to the specific file name

```
        public static bool TrimContains(List<string> names, string name)
        {
            return names.Any(x => x.Trim().Equals(name.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
```

and your final code would become

```
        List<string> fileList = new List<string>() { "file1", "file5", "file6" };

        foreach (var clientDoc in clientDocList.Where(c => !TrimContains(fileList, c.DocFileName)))
        {
            //TextResult += $" {clientDoc.DocFileName} does not exists so you have to delete it from db";
            documentRepository.Delete(clientDoc);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retrieving all documents from database and do the checking in memory, I suggest to check which document doesn't exist in folder in one query:

```
if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
{
    var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Select(Path.GetFileName);
    var clientDocList = documentRepository.Documents.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientID && !fileList.Contains(c.DocFileName.Trim())).ToList();
    documentRepository.Documents.RemoveRange(clientDocList);
}
```

Note: this is just a sample to demonstrate the idea, may have syntax error somewhere since I don't have IDE with me at the moment. But the idea is there

This code is not only shorter but also more efficient since it only uses a single query to retrieve documents from database. I assume the number of files in a folder is not too large to convert to SQL by EF